# Codigo Python para gerar evento na Agenda Google

Tags: python, google, gmail

Gostaria de uma ajudar para criar um código usando Python para gerar eventos na agenda do Google, já tenho a API configurada e lançada para esta ação, mas não consigo fazer meu código funcionar, já fiz esse processo para o envio de Emails e funcionou perfeitamente. Eu sou novo com este tipo de desenvolvimento e gostaria de uma ajuda para colocar esse código para funcionar, o site do Google não está ajudando muito com os exemplos disponíveis.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import service
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

import datetime

try:
import argparse
flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
flags = None

 If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
at ~/.credentials/calendar-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 
'C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Codigos 
Funcionando\\Agenda\\client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Agenda'
MANUAL_AUTH = True


def get_credentials():
"""Gets valid user credentials from storage.

If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

Returns:
    Credentials, the obtained credential.
"""
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)
credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                               'calendar-python-quickstart.json')

store = Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()
if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
return credentials

def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.

Creates a Google Calendar API service object and outputs a list of the next
10 events on the user's calendar.
"""
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
eventsResult = service.events().list(
    calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()

evento = {
    'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer 
products.',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': '2017-11-22T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': '2017-11-22T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
    },
    'recurrence': [
        'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
    ],
    'attendees': [
         {'email': 'XXXXXX@XXXXcom.com.br'},
         {'email': 'XXXXXX@XXXXcom.com.br'},
     ],
     'reminders': {
         'useDefault': False,
         'overrides': [
             {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
             {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
         ],
     },
 }


 evento = service.events().insert(calendarId='XXXX@metodotelecom.com.br', 
body=evento).execute()
 print('Event created: %s' % (evento.get('htmlLink')))

created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
    calendarId='primary',
    text='Appointment at Somewhere on June 3rd 10am-10:25am').execute()

print
created_event['id']
```

Ja tentei alguns exemplos do site de ajuda do Google porem sem muito sucesso, gostaria muito de uma ajuda para conseguir colocar este codigo para funcionar, ate a parte da autenticação esta funcionando mas quando tento gerar um evento na agenda que esta dando erro.

Erro

```
import service File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\service_init_.py", line 34, in <module> from daemon import DaemonContext File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\daemon_init_.py", line 42, in <module> from .daemon import DaemonContext File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\daemon\daemon.py", line 25, in <module> import pwd
```

Comment: Que erro está dando? Insira o log ou partes do mesmo.

Comment: import service
  File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\service\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from daemon import DaemonContext
  File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\daemon\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .daemon import DaemonContext
  File "C:\Users\RodrigoAugusto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\daemon\daemon.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pwd